# Cropping greyscale images within larger images using OpenCV and python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, crop

Hi I'm new to python and opencv. I've got this image: [image: this]

I'm trying to crop the greyscale images from the picture. At the moment, the code finds the biggest bounding box i.e. the top right image and then crops it. What I want to do is find all the greyscale images even if there are more than 4 in the picture and crop all of them. I'm thinking of using a loop to do it but I don't want to set a loop where it finds the largest bounding boxes 4 times and then stops as other images that I'm processing would have more than 4 images in it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('multi.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to grayscale
# threshold to get just the signature (INVERTED)
retval, thresh_gray = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh=100, maxval=255, \
                                    type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray,cv2.RETR_LIST, \
                                              cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Find object with the biggest bounding box
mx = (0,0,0,0)      # biggest bounding box so far
mx_area = 0
for cont in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
    area = w*h
    if area > mx_area:
        mx = x,y,w,h
        mx_area = area
x,y,w,h = mx

# Find object with the biggest bounding box

mx = (0,0,0,0)      # biggest bounding box so far
mx_area = 0
for cont in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
    area = w*h
    if area > mx_area:
        mx = x,y,w,h
        mx_area = area
x,y,w,h = mx

# Output to files
roi=img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite('Image_crop.jpg', roi)

cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(200,0,0),2)
cv2.imwrite('Image_cont.jpg', img)
```

Comment: You can find the area of contours using `cv.contourArea(cnt)` from [HERE](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html). Set a threshold for the area above which contours must be found and crop them

Comment: The problem is the greyscale image are not the same sizes. Some are big and some are small but they're all bigger than the text and the range shown at the bottom.

Comment: I have added an answer with 10000 as the area threshold. You can use a different value since the boxes **are bigger** than the text and the range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have elaborated my comment.

In the code provided by you, the contours are found using `cv2.RETR_LIST` which every possible contour in the image including those present within contours. I have used `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` which ignores those contours within other contours.

```
image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Desktop\g.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

retval, thresh_gray = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh=100, maxval=255, \
                                    type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow('thresh_gray.png', thresh_gray)

image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,                                                 cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    if cv2.contourArea(c) > 10000:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        roi = image[y  :y + h, x : x + w ]

        cv2.imshow('Region_{}.jpg'.format(i), roi)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly now. The only problem is the images that are being produced have different numbers rather than Image_crop 1.jpg, Image_crop 2.jpg, Image_crop 3.jpg and Image_crop 4.jpg, it says Image_crop 5.jpg, Image_crop 6.jpg, Image_crop 20.jpg and Image_crop 67.jpg.

Comment: @AbidAbdulGafoor So you want the new image to be renamed by actual name followed by a number?

Comment: I want the numbers to be consistent and in a consecutive order rather than random if you get what I mean?

Comment: To do so you can save the resulting images with the actual filename followed by a number like: `cv2.imwrite('{}_region_{}'.format(filename, st), img)`

Comment: Might be a stupid question but I'm not sure what st is?

Comment: I did a while loop and it kind of works. Is this okay?     `while True: | j+=1 | cv2.imwrite('Image_crop {}.jpg'.format(j), roi) | break`

Comment: @AbidAbdulGafoor It looks good. But I hope it is sufficient for you.